# C# Forms Code help - Use CSV file

Tags: c#, forms, csv

I have this code and would like to use a csv file containing a username and password. I dont want to use the set username and instead a username from a csv file in column 1 and a password in column 2.
Please can someone help me modify a login system which is a simple 2 text boxes and a button which can read to check the entered values against a csv file.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user, password;
    user = textBox1.Text;
    password = textBox2.Text;
    if ((user == "admin") && (password == "1234567"))
    {
        //then show form2
        this.Hide();
        var form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        form2.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        //if username and password is incorrect show this message box
        MessageBox.Show("Username or Password Invalid");
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Search for _open file_, _read file content_, _split a string at separator_ Of course I hope this is just an exercise because there is no security in this approach

Comment: I like to read files using ( `StreamReader` )[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline(v=vs.110).aspx] and for your case, [Split the readed line by ","](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)  `file = new StreamReader(folder + filName); while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) { foreach (string inputOnFile in line.Split(',')){ fileContent.Add(inputOnFile); }} file.Close();`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not recommending this because it means reading the entire CSV file (or at least up until a match) every single time someone logs in. (And because in real life we wouldn't store this in a CSV file.) But just for the fun of it, here's the code.

```
public class CsvFileUserCredentialsValidator 
{
    private readonly string _filePath;

    public CsvFileUserCredentialsValidator(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public bool UserCredentialsAreValid(string userName, string password)
    {
        //Open the file. Because of the "using" block the StreamReader will
        //always get disposed regardless of how the function returns. That
        //means the file won't be left open.
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(_filePath))
        {
            //Continue while we're not at the end of the file
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Read a line
                var line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                //If the line is empty skip to the next line.
                if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

                //Split it by comma.
                var split = line.Split(',');

                //If there aren't exactly two values then something isn't right
                //with this line. Ignore it and go to the next line.
                if (split.Length != 2) continue;

                //Compare the two values to see if they match the user and pw.
                //Username isn't case-sensitive but password is.
                //If it's a match return true. The username and password are valid.
                //Because we're returning true we won't read any more from the file.
                if (string.Equals(split[0], userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
                    && string.Equals(split[1], password, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    return true;
            }

            //We went through the whole file without a match. Return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
}

var validator = new CsvFileUserCredentialsValidator(pathToYourCsvFile);
var isValid = validator.UserCredentialsAreValid(username, password);
```

Comment: I have it as follows,

Comment: Thanks, just a little more help on what to do after. Check my next post.

Comment: If this answers *this* question please mark it as answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    public CsvFileUserCredentialsValidator(string filePath)
    {
        _filePath = filePath;
    }

    public bool UserCredentialsAreValid(string userName, string password)
    {
        //Open the file. Because of the "using" block the StreamReader will
        //always get disposed regardless of how the function returns. That
        //means the file won't be left open.
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(_filePath))
        {
            //Continue while we're not at the end of the file
            while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                //Read a line
                var line = streamReader.ReadLine();

                //If the line is empty skip to the next line.
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(line)) continue;

                //Split it by comma.
                var split = line.Split(',');

                //If there aren't exactly two values then something isn't right
                //with this line. Ignore it and go to the next line.
                if (split.Length != 2) continue;

                //Compare the two values to see if they match the user and pw.
                //Username isn't case-sensitive but password is.
                //If it's a match return true. The username and password are valid.
                //Because we're returning true we won't read any more from the file.
                if (string.Equals(split[0], userName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                    && string.Equals(split[1], password, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    return true;
            }

            //We went through the whole file without a match. Return false.
            return false;
        }
    }
}


public Form1();


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
```

var validator = new CsvFileUserCredentialsValidator(pathToYourCsvFile);
    var isValid = validator.UserCredentialsAreValid(username, password);
    public partial class Form1 : Form;`enter code here`
        }